# login() in Django testing framework

Tags: python, django, testing, authentication

I have started using Django's testing framework, and everything was working fine until I started testing authenticated pages.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say that this is a test:

```
class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user('temporary', 'temporary@gmail.com', 'temporary')

    def test_secure_page(self):
        c = Client()
        print c.login(username='temporary', password='temporary')
        response = c.get('/users/secure/', follow=True)
        user = User.objects.get(username='temporary')
        self.assertEqual(response.context['email'], 'temporary@gmail.com')
```

After I run this test, it fails, and I see that printing return value of login() returns *True*, but *response.content* gets redirected to login page (if login fails authentication decorator redirects to login page). I have put a break point in decorator that does authentication:

```
def authenticate(user):
    if user.is_authenticated():
        return True
    return False
```

and it really returns *False*. Line 4 in test_secure_page() properly retrieves user.

This is the view function:

```
@user_passes_test(authenticate, login_url='/users/login')
def secure(request):
    user = request.user
    return render_to_response('secure.html', {'email': user.email})
```

Of course, if I try to login through application (outside of test), everything works fine.

Comment: And please post the code of the view you're testing.

Comment: @S.Lott I was not testing my login page (although I tried that as well, but that's not working neither), but rest of the "secure" part of the system. For that reason, I tried using login().

Comment: @kevin.  The issue is that the post to login creates a cookie that is then used by the client.  No cookie, no secure access.  AFAIK, the `login()` function doesn't create the cookie and return it to the client.  Can you try to reproduce the examples in the Django documentation and see if they work for you?

Answer (score 36):

The problem is that you're not passing `RequestContext` to your template.

Also, you probably should use the `login_required` decorator and the client built in the `TestCase` class.

I'd rewrite it like this:

```
#views.py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

@login_required(login_url='/users/login')
def secure(request):
    user = request.user
    return render(request, 'secure.html', {'email': user.email})



#tests.py
class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        user = User.objects.create_user('temporary', 'temporary@gmail.com', 'temporary')

    def test_secure_page(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        self.client.login(username='temporary', password='temporary')
        response = self.client.get('/manufacturers/', follow=True)
        user = User.objects.get(username='temporary')
        self.assertEqual(response.context['email'], 'temporary@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Why do you think that not passing RequestContext should be a problem (context is given to render_to_response())? It works outside of testing framework when this is invoked from browser (btw, I tried passing RequestContext, but the same thing happens). Also, authentication happens before view is entered. I tried @login_required and client from TestCase class as well, but again same thing happens.

Comment: I made it work by changing: self.assertEqual(response.context['user'].email, 'temporary@gmail.com')

Answer (score 13):

It can often be useful to use a custom auth backend that bypassess any sort of authentication during testing:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class TestcaseUserBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, testcase_user=None):
        return testcase_user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        User = get_user_model()
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
```

Then, during tests, add `yourapp.auth_backends.TestcaseUserBackend` to your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "akindi.testing.auth_backends.TestcaseUserBackend",
]
```

Then, during tests, you can simply call:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
user = User.objects.get(…)
login(testcase_user=user)
```

Comment: getting `: login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'testcase_user'` any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `login` is from `django.contrib.auth` (see edited post)? And are you sure the backend is being correctly added?

Answer (score 1):

Token based authentication:
I was in same situation. I found solution in which actually I did generate a user for login purpose in `setUp` method. Then later in the test methods, I tried to get the token and passed it along with request data.

**setUp:**

1. create a user

```python
self.pravesh = User.objects.create(
     email='psj.aaabbb@gmail.com',
     first_name='Pravesh',
     last_name='aaabbb',
     phone='5456165156',
     phonecountrycode='91'
)
```

2. set password for the user

```python
self.password = 'example password'
self.pravesh.set_password(self.password)
```

**test_method:**

1. create client

```python
client.login(email=self.pravesh.email, password=self.password)
```

2. get token (in case of token auth)

```python
token = Token.objects.create(user=self.pravesh)
```

3. pass login information

```python
response = client.post(
    reverse('account:post-data'),
    data = json.dumps(self.data),
    HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token {}'.format(token),
    content_type = 'application/json'
)
```

Comment: I tries your solution but I still get error 401, will you plase check my question and help me?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311866/djnago-unittest-clien-get-error-401-even-if-i-send-token